# Hoeffding inequality

Tags: machine-learning, hoeffdings-inequality

I came across these questions online : 
As known, Learning relies that the Hoeffding inequality holds. In what way? 
Can you give an example where it doesn’t hold? 
I know what is the meaning of Hoeffding inequality, but I don't know how to answer these questions.

Comment: Can you clarify ? " As known, Learning relies that the Hoeffding inequality holds. In what way? " it is not known to me and I don't understand what you mean by "Learning" here, learning is a very general term and you don't need Hoeffding for all of Machine Learning methods to hold.

Comment: I don't know what is the meaning of learning. I saw this question and thought maybe someone can clarify me what is the meaning.